# Select new item added to SwiftUI List

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Using Xcode 11.0, Beta 5.

I have a `List` driven from an array of model objects in an observed view model. Each item in the `List` has a `NavigationLink` with a destination detail view/view model that accepts the model as an argument.

The user can tap a bar button above the list to add a new item which is added to the view model's array and the `List` is therefore reloaded with the new item displayed.

The issue I cannot solve is how to *select* that new item in the list and therefore display the detail view without needing the user to select it manually. (This is an iPad app with split screen view, hence the reason to want to select it)

I've tried using a `NavigationLink` programatically, but can't seem to get anything to work. I looked at the `selection` argument for the `List` but that also requires the list to be in edit mode, so that's no good.

Any suggestions are very welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution uses the `selection` attribute of `NavigationLink`. One problem here is that only items *currently visible* get rendered, so selecting a row further down does nothing.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()

    var title: String
    var content: String
}

struct ItemOverview: View {
    let item: Item

    var body: some View {
        Text(item.title)
    }
}

struct ItemDetailsView: View {
    let item: Item

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(item.title).font(.headline)
            Divider()
            Text(item.content)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

func randomString(length: Int) -> String {
    let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    return String((0..<length).map{ _ in letters.randomElement()! })
}

struct ListSelectionView: View {
    @State var items: [Item] = [
        Item(title: "Hello", content: "Content World"),
        Item(title: "Hey", content: "Content Du"),
    ]
    @State var selection: UUID? = nil

    func createItem() {
        let newItem = Item(title: randomString(length: 3), content: randomString(length: 10))
        self.selection = newItem.id
        self.items.append(newItem)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            NavigationView{
                List(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ItemDetailsView(item: item), tag: item.id, selection: self.$selection, label: {
                        Text(item.title)
                    })
                }
            }
            Button(action: {
                self.createItem()

            }) { Text("Add and select new item") }
            Divider()
            Text("Current selection2: \(String(selection?.uuidString ?? "not set"))")
        }
    }
}
```

A second problem is that changing the `$selection` makes `Modifying state during view update` appear.

Third problem is that after manual *selection* the `shading` stays on the same item until again changed by hand.

### Result

Programmatic selection is not really usable for now if you want to select a link not initialized yet (not visible?).

### Further ideas

One might look into tags a little bit more.

Another option could be paging where all items of the current page are visible.

One could also use list selection and show details based on that.

Comment: As you mention, this is not ideal in terms of performance and am having some issues, but it certainly does seem to be the intended way of doing this. Hopefully some of the issues will be resolved as we move towards GM. Thanks for your help!